# How do I validate_uniqueness_of when scoped to two attributes only when one attribute on matching existing records does not equal a specific value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, validates-uniqueness-of

I have an `Invitation` model that represents an invitation to join a subscription.  There should only be one `Invitation` at any given time with a specific `email` / `subscription_id` combination unless the other records with the matching `email` / `subscription_id` also have a `state` of `'declined'`.

I can currently validate for uniqueness given that the email and subscription_id combination is unique:

**My `Invitation` model:**

```
validates :email, :uniqueness => { :scope => :subscription_id }
```

**Rspec (passes):**

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:email).scoped_to(:subscription_id) }
```

However, I want to skip the uniqueness check if the matching model(s) in the database have a `state` that is equal to `'declined'`.

If the existing model's state is 'declined', the validation should pass.

The first thing that comes to mind is:

```
validates :email, :uniqueness => { :scope => :subscription_id },
                                   :unless => lambda { |asset| asset.state == 'declined' }
```

But this is wrong because it checks if the newly created model has a state of 'declined', I want to check if the previously existing records have a state of `'declined'`.

I also tried this:

```
validates :email, :uniqueness => { :scope => :subscription_id, :message => 'subscriptionery do' }, 
                                   :if => lambda { |asset| asset.state == 'declined' }
```

But that fails for what I assume is the same reason.

*How would I write a validation that checks an additional scope?*

---

I feel like writing something like the following, but this is just made up syntax to help explain my idea:

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:email).scoped_to(:subscription_id) } 
                                   unless MyModel.where(:email == new_object.email,
                                                        :subscription_id == new_object.subscription_id,
                                                        :state == 'declined')
```

---

**Update:**

I did this and it worked:

```
validates :email, uniqueness: { scope: :subscription_id, message: 'The email address %{value} is already associated with this subscription.' }, if: :state_of_others_are_not_declined?, on: :create

def state_of_others_are_not_declined?
  Invitation.where(email: email).where(subscription_id: subscription_id).where.not(state: 'declined').any?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this work for you;

```
validate :unique_email_with_subscription_and_state


def unique_email_with_subscription_and_state
    errors.add(:email,"YOUR MESSAGE") if Invitation.where(email: self.email, subscription_id: self.subscription_id).where.not(state: 'declined').any?
end
```

This will select all `Invitiation`s where the the `email` matches, `subscription_id` matches   and the `state` is not declined. If it finds any it will add an `error` to `:email`. Something like this

```
"SELECT invitations.* FROM invitatations WHERE email = 'me@example.com' AND subscription_id = 2 AND state <> 'declined'"
```

Is that the desired result?

Comment: Really close to what I got to work just as you posted this.  I'm sure your solution would have worked as well as it is very similar to the solution I came up with.